# Merging newer answer from closed duplicate question

Tags: discussion

Sooo, it seems like there was an interesting little dustup over the last couple of hours over which one of these duplicate question threads should be closed:

[Why do the major and minor groove exist in DNA?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/25925/784)

[How do major and minor grooves arise in the DNA helix?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/43647/784)

I wrote the accepted answer for the first question, and @David wrote the answer for the second question. It seems like the mods decided to close the thread with David's answer on the basis that it a couple of years younger.

I'm not crazy about the text of David's answer, but his illustration is pretty awesome. I think he really hit the nail on the head when it comes to giving a viewer an intuitive sense of how the geometry of the individual bases give rise to the particular grooves in the 3D helix. I'd like to merge the two answers (with David's permission, of course).

What's the SE policy about this kind of answer merging? Should the final result be a community wiki or something?

Comment: I commented that perhaps the questions should be merged. I think both posts would then appear as answers to a single question.

Comment: @canadianer that is a much simpler idea than mine. I like it!

Comment: I think a moderator can do it. That said, I'm not sure if there is any particular downside for having one question closed as a duplicate of the other since the answer can still be voted up.

Comment: Don't like the proposal. It is absolutely ok to have 2 different answers to a single question.

Comment: The moderators seem to be MIA.

Comment: I see it the way @AlwaysConfused does it. There is no way to either merge questions or answers.

Comment: @Chris What about [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158066/what-are-merged-questions)?

Comment: @Chris I whole-heartedly support candianer's [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158066/what-are-merged-questions). The questions are short and nearly identical. There probably are cases where it would be complicated to merge the questions, but this isn't one of them.

Answer (score 2):

Please don't.

Because while merging 2 answer;

1. The moderator may ignore or miss a point that the answerer intended to handover the asker/ visitor.
2. Usually all answers are correct here. The cause behind the difference in the answers is the various way of explaining, or how the answerer is taking the asker's problem. On the same questions multiple answers have multiple views or tastes. So it is absolutely OK to have multiple answers to a single question.
3. It hurts the answerer's right for the material they contributed.

.........................................

Rather, your proposal would work better if it was about merging duplicate questions, not its answers. And also not a complete fusion, but as separate sections ("some other users also wanted to know almost the same... such as section-1, section-2, etc") if you want to keep some different points from duplicated question.

But for answer; it is not needed. Ant that is NOT "simple", too. So the best way is to keep all answers undeleted but separate.

Comment: Thanks for this answer.